# How to remove numbering in article

Tags: sectioning

I'm newbie in LaTeX so my question may seem a bit obvious. The issue is I want to remove the number before a section's title. For instance

```
\section{Section name}
```

produces the output, say,

> 3 Section name

But I want just “Section name” without “3”. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Use `\section*{Section name}`.

Comment: @St.Antario Is it for a single section or for all of them?

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` would omit numbers for all levels from `\section` on down, but that value may differ depending on what document class you're using.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Would you care answering?

Answer (score 5):

`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` would omit numbers for all levels from `\section` on down, but that value may differ depending on what document class you're using.